# Jordillonch CrudGeneratorBundle How to filter on date ranges?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm building an application on Symfony 2.1 with jordillonch/CrudGeneratorBundle
Its a great CRUD - simple filter feature works fine

But now I need a more complexe filter feature :
I need to filter on a date range

Is there anyone who can give me some hints ? Would be great !

Answer (score 0):

Ok - I did not think to get it work - but using Lexik and filter_date_range
it was finally so easy :)